# completing square for a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, completing-the-square

In the following question: 
[image: function picture]

I don't understand how we can get from the original equation to the final equation using completing the square.

Any thoughts as how to get to the final equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x + y = c(x^2 + y^2 + 1)$

$x^2 + y^2 - \frac xc - \frac yc + 1 = 0$

$x^2 - \frac xc + (\frac 1{2c})^2- (\frac 1{2c})^2 + y^2 - \frac yc + (\frac y{2c})^2- (\frac 1{2c})^2+ 1 = 0$

$(x - \frac 1{2c})^2 + (y-\frac 1{2c})^2 + 1 - \frac 1{4c^2} - \frac 1{4c^2} = 0$

$(x - \frac 1{2c})^2 + (y-\frac 1{2c})^2 = \frac 1{2c^2} -1$.

It's.... completing the square and exactly what it says.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to avoid fractions completely until the last step.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2+1}&=c\\
x+y&=c(x^2+y^2+1)\\
x+y&=cx^2+cy^2+c\\
cx^2-x+cy^2-y+c&=0\\
cx^2-x+cy^2-y&=-c\\
4c(cx^2-x+cy^2-y)&=4c(-c)\\
4c^2x^2-4cx+4c^2y^2-4cy&=-4c^2\\
(2cx)^2-2(2cx)+(2cy)^2-2(2cy)&=-4c^2\\
(2cx)^2-2(2cx)+1+(2cy)^2-2(2cy)+1&=2-4c^2\\
(2cx-1)^2 + (2cy-1)^2 &= 2-4c^2\\
\frac{(2cx-1)^2 + (2cy-1)^2}{4c^2} &= \frac{2-4c^2}{4c^2}\\
\bigg(x-\frac{1}{2c}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(y-\frac{1}{2c}\bigg)^2 &= \frac{1}{2c^2}-1\\
\end{align}$$